# Where are the opencv2 include files?

Tags: opencv, installation, header-files

I'm struggling to find the include files that should be in a directory names "opencv2"! I've downloaded OpenCV-2.4.0.tar.bz2 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/latest/download?source=files) and extracted the files and ran cmake, which seemed to build the library successfully.

The problem is that under the "include" directory for "opencv2" there seem to be tons of header files missing. The only header file there at the moment is "opencv.hpp", which includes a whole set of other files which aren't there. Does anyone have any idea where I can get these files from?

[image: Picture of the "opencv2" directory.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The header files of the modules are in their own directories. E.g., you can find `calib3d.hpp` in `/modules/calib3d/include/opencv2/calib3d`. The Makefile created by CMake knows these addresses, hence when you `make install` the header files are all copied into `/usr/local/include/opencv2`.

Comment: Ahh I had only issued a `make` command and needed to do a `make install`! Thanks! Do you know how I can set the install path to change it from /usr/local/include etc.? Thanks again!

Comment: call `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` or any other directory you want instead of `/usr`.

Answer (score 19):

In case you were using cmake-gui and visual studio on Windows to make opencv (I had 3.4.0), don't forget to build this project:

[image]

This will generate all required files in a single folder, so you can easily connect header files:

[image]