# Opencv - Can't find header files

Tags: c++, opencv, header, cmake, header-files

I'm trying to start development with opencv. The problem is, until now I coul barely setup the opencv cos I cant find its header files.

I made some research regarding to this subject but none of them were realy helpful, below some of the links:

1. [Where are the opencv2 include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588400/where-are-the-opencv2-include-files)
2. http://answers.opencv.org/question/14712/opencvhpp-not-in-opencv2/

I made the built the files using CMAKE GUI - Built the code with MVS 11 x64 both debug and release. The compilation suceeded and I cant found libs and dlls, but no headers at all anywhere.

Checkout the pics:

Opencv2 folder

[image]

Local folder

[image]

So, now I ask, What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help

EDIT ONE:

[image]

[image]

Is that what you meant?

EDIT TWO:

[image]

I found some headers inside the source of opencv, and each of them is inside an specific folder, like core, highgui and so on - that is it? or something still wrong? cos I thought I should take the headers on the build, no on the source..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

append "opencv/build/include" to your include path.

if you built the opencv libraries yourself using cmake, make sure you run the INSTALL project, and add the folder, where it installed to.

When you run `make install` then the include files that you need are copied to a single directory determined by the makefiles and probably displayed as a part of the output.

Comment: The SDK is an apart folder from the source, dont need to specify "build" - I built the project, and only built, as far as I know thats enough to compile the source, I didnt run, so am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, its there, thought I would find at the build after CMAKE, but correct the path on your answer therefore I can accept

Comment: Its not on the SDK, its on the source "opencv/build/include" correct again pls

Answer (score 2):

I know what's going on. After built the entire solution, under the "opencv" solution strcutre, there is a folder called "CMakeTargets", expand this folder, you can see "INSTALL" project, and right-click this project, then select "build" option, then after installation, all libraries and head files will be located at the correct path. Like the following picture shows:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0km8c.png)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the settings that were in use when you built OpenCV - the include path **must** point to where the include files are for your build to have succeeded.

Comment: Have you looked in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Open CV SDK/` and it's subdirectories?

Comment: Also open the cmake files __in a text editor__ and look for `-I` directives or other thing that mention "include".