# SOLVED - "fatal error: opencv: no such file or directory" in Sublime Text for c++

Tags: c++, opencv, sublimetext3

I'm not having any success with `#include <opencv>`, no matter what I try. [EDIT: I've also tried `#include <opencv2>` and `#include <opencv4>`, but there was no difference].

For context, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, using Sublime Text 3, the latest version of OpenCV is installed on the system (at `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2`), and I've tried something like six different build systems for cpp, including the default.

no matter what I try and how I fiddle with files, I always get the same error:

```
/home/user/Projects/Mind/CScript/Script.cpp:5:10: fatal error: opencv: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <opencv>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/home/user/Projects/Mind/CScript/Script.cpp" -o "/home/user/Projects/Mind/CScript/Script" && "/home/user/Projects/Mind/CScript/Script"]
[dir: /home/user/Projects/Mind/CScript]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

I even tried to copy the whole opencv folder into the file path, but there was no change at all.

EDIT: The solution that worked was to paste the opencv2 folder from `/usr/local/include/opencv4/` to `/usr/local/include/`. Apparently that additional folder wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv` a file that exists? That folder seems like a non-standard include folder (in that it's a subdirectory of one) but the command line isn't specifying `-I` to set the include path. Does this command work if you run it outside of Sublime?

Comment: I was a bit imprecise, in that the last folder of the path is `/opencv2`, and it contains all the relevant files. I've tried with adding `"-I /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2"` to the build-system file, but it didn't solve the problem. I've tried `#include <opencv2>` and `<opencv4>`, same error. I've tried adding specific files in the folder as headers, nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opencv - Can't find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343984/opencv-cant-find-header-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `#include` refers to a file, not a folder. A file so specified is looked for in the list of include paths.

`-I /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2` adds that path to the list of include paths. The path, however, looks broken to me -- OpenCV has the legacy API in `opencv/`, and the updated API in `opencv2/`, but in either case there should be no `opencv4/` in the path. (Double-checked with my APT.) Are you sure you did the OpenCV setup correctly?

The actual header's name is [opencv2/opencv.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.3.0/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp) (note the `.hpp` at the end; generally, only the standard library's includes are without `.hpp`, all the third party libs I have seen so far use the `.hpp` extension).

Best practice is to leave the include path alone and write `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` (with the subdirectory name) in your sources to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I remember installing opencv from a tutorial, and getting the expected feedback throughout. I remember never specifying a specific path, but it could very well be that I've installed it incorrectly.
As for `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"`, that's literally the first thing I tried, and it still gives me back the same error. I've also tried with `<>`, no difference. I think at this point I must have tried every possible variation of it.

Comment: @Batrax this is a long shot but have you tried with `<opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>`?

Comment: It works now! I've just simply moved the opencv2 folder from opencv4 to its parent. Apparently it was a problem of broken path, like you said, but I have no idea where the opencv4 folder came from. Anyway, thank you for the help!